# iPhone: xml parser for ajax

Tags: iphone, xml, parsing

I'm developing an app for iPhone. I'm trying to parse an xml made with ajax, with a tag named response. The parser I've been using is TBXML, which performs pretty ok with any XML, but the ones made with ajax!

Is there another parser that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean for "xml made with ajax". the response should be the same. Or maybe do you get a json response? In that case you could use [TouchJSON](https://github.com/schwa/TouchJSON)